# OSGI bundle (or service)- how to register for a given time period?

Tags: time, osgi, period

Search did not give me a hint, how can i behave with the following situation:

I'd love to have 2 OSGI implementations of the same interface: one is regular, the other should work (be active/present/whatever) on the given time period (f.e for Christmas weeks :))

The main goal is to call the **same** interface without specifying any flags/properties/without manual switching of *ranking*. Application should somehow switch implementation for this special period, doing another/regular job before and after :)

I'm a newbie, maybe i do not completely understand OSGI concept somewhere, sorry for that of give me a hint or link, sorry for my English.

Using Felix/Equinox with Apache Aries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have yet to see an OSGI container that at a framework level supports date/time based availability of services.

If I were you I would simply drop a proxy service in front of the two interface implementations and put the service invocation based on date logic in there.

Answer (score 3):

The publisher of a service can register and unregister that service whenever it likes using the normal API. If it chooses then it can do so according to some regular schedule.

If there is another service instance that is available continuously, then the consumer of the service will sometimes see two instances of the service and sometimes see one. When there is only one instance available then it is trivial to get only that instance. When there are two instances then you need a way to ensure you get your "preferred" instance. The SERVICE_RANKING property is a way to do this. The `getService` method of a normal `ServiceTracker` will always return the higher ranked service, so this would appear to satisfy your requirement.

Comment: i know about ranking, in blueprint it is setup only via xml, not dynamically on a fly.

Comment: Why does the ranking need to be setup on the fly?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is any framework support for what you are asking for.

If you are intent on avoiding service filters, you might try this.

Implement a PolicyService.  This service is in charge of deciding which instance of your service should be registered at a given point in time.  When its time for the policy service to switch implementations, it just uses the register/unregister apis as usual.  You policy service implementation can read in a config file that specifies the date range to service implementation mapping.  This will allow you to add new behavior by modifying your config file and installing a new bundle with the new service.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Neil that a service should only publish itself if it can actually be invoked. My solution to this problem would be to have all service producers be dependent on a "time constraint dependency". Whilst such a dependency is not available in the standard dependency frameworks (like Declarative Services, Blueprint, iPOJO) it is easily implemented with the Apache Felix Dependency Manager, which allows you to create your own types of dependencies. Note that writing such a new dependency once is some work, but if this is a core piece of your application I think it's worth it. Service consumers would not require any special logic, they would simply invoke the service that was there.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, what i have finally done...

1. Implemented a common dispatcher bundle - and call any of services only thru it (therefore cron is not needed, when call is on-demand)
2. When dispatcher obtains request - it searches for interface in its own cache and -
3. When there are >1 service with the same ranking and both are equal (registered) - then
4. Dispatcher resolves needed service via own written @TimigPolicy annotation with "from" and "to" fields
5. For the given server new datetime() - dispatcher returns proper service instance

Much work, i should say :) But works nearly perfect :)

Thanks everybody for giving me hints, it was really helpful!!!